# Can I use C# Serialization to read a binary file in custom format?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary-data

I have a custom binary file which I want to read into my C# program.

There are several different formats, some MSB first, some LSB first and some with the variables in different orders.

Currently, I have a class which reads the right number of bytes, one at a time.

It is very slow and so I am looking to improve performance any way I can.

Is serialization likely to perform better? If so, is this possible with the scenario I have decsribed? Is it possible to customise the BinaryFormatter for big/little-endian format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `BinaryFormatter` - it will expect additional meta-data/padding around object. You would have to read manually either from a `Stream` or similarly via a binary reader.

Having done some very similar code, I would write my own reader that sits on top of a stream, with methods like: `ReadInt32LittleEndian`, `ReadInt32BigEndian` (etc for everything you need) - and use shift (`<<` / `>>`) to assemble the bytes. But *importantly* I would use a backing buffer to reduce the amount of calls to the underlying stream (even with a buffer, this can be unacceptably slow).

Let me refer you to some code from protobuf-net that does this... in particular [`ProtoReader`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ProtoReader.cs), taking an example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads an unsigned 32-bit integer from the stream; supported wire-types: Variant, Fixed32, Fixed64
    /// </summary>
    public uint ReadUInt32()
    {
        switch (wireType)
        {
            case WireType.Variant:
                return ReadUInt32Variant(false);
            case WireType.Fixed32:
                if (available < 4) Ensure(4, true);
                position += 4;
                available -= 4;
                return ((uint)ioBuffer[ioIndex++])
                    | (((uint)ioBuffer[ioIndex++]) << 8)
                    | (((uint)ioBuffer[ioIndex++]) << 16)
                    | (((uint)ioBuffer[ioIndex++]) << 24);
            case WireType.Fixed64:
                ulong val = ReadUInt64();
                checked { return (uint)val; }
            default:
                throw CreateException();
        }
    }
```

(here `wireType` *broadly* acts as an indicater of endianness etc, but that isn't important)

Looking at the `Fixed32` implementation:

- The `Ensure` makes sure that we have at least 4 more bytes in our backing buffer (fetching more if we desire)
- we increment some counters so we can track our position in the logical buffer
- we read the data *from the buffer*

One you have a reader for your format, deserialization should be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

No it wont work. Well it could, but the overhead from a transformation will likely kill performance.